# Why oozie needs database?

Tags: hadoop, derby, bigdata, oozie

I have installed apache oozie version4.1.2 in my system..
While installation i created a database for oozie using the following command.

ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run (in linux)

Why does oozie need a database?
What will it store in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Oozie stores the workflow/scheduler details and others in the db. The status of the running jobs and the earlier jobs can be accessed from the console.

[image]